# Convert IEnumerable<Task<T>> to IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I'm trying to use the Reactive Extensions (Rx) to buffer an enumeration of Tasks as they complete. Does anyone know if there is a clean built-in way of doing this? The `ToObservable` extension method will just make an `IObservable<Task<T>>`, which is not what I want, I want an `IObservable<T>`, that I can then use `Buffer` on.

Contrived example:

```
//Method designed to be awaitable
public static Task<int> makeInt()
{
     return Task.Run(() => 5);
}

//In practice, however, I don't want to await each individual task
//I want to await chunks of them at a time, which *should* be easy with Observable.Buffer 
public static void Main() 
{
    //Make a bunch of tasks
    IEnumerable<Task<int>> futureInts = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(t => makeInt());

    //Is there a built in way to turn this into an Observable that I can then buffer?
    IObservable<int> buffered = futureInts.TasksToObservable().Buffer(15); //????

    buffered.Subscribe(ints => {
        Console.WriteLine(ints.Count()); //Should be 15
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500456/how-to-convert-an-ienumerabletaskt-to-iobservablet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the fact that `Task` can be converted to observable using [another overload of `ToObservable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211785%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

When you have a collection of (single-item) observables, you can create a single observable that contains the items as they complete using [`Merge()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229590%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

So, your code could look like this:

```
futureInts.Select(t => t.ToObservable())
          .Merge()
          .Buffer(15)
          .Subscribe(ints => Console.WriteLine(ints.Count));
```

Comment: By any chance is there an easy way of converting `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` to `IObservable<T>` with the results of `Task<T>` being a stream of results in `IObservable<T>`?

Comment: @JonathanPeel I think `task.ToObservable().SelectMany(x => x)` should work.