# How to pass an async method inside the Observable.Do extension method?

Tags: system.reactive

Given:

1. `IObservable<T> src`
2. `async Task F(T){...}`.
3. `F` can only be called sequentially. So `await F(x);await F(y);` is fine, but `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[]{F(x),F(y)}, _ => {...});` is wrong, because `F(x)` and `F(y)` must not run concurrently.

It is clear to me that `await src.Do(F)` is wrong, because it would run `F` concurrently.

My question is how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use TPL Dataflow, which will throttle to a single concurrent invocation by default, even for asynchronous methods:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<T>(F);
src.Subscribe(block.AsObserver());
await block.Completion;
```

Alternatively, you could subscribe an asynchronous method that you throttle yourself:

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
src.Do(async x =>
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    await F(x);
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`Observable.Do` is for side effects only, not for sequential composition.  `SelectMany` may be what you want.  As of Rx 2.0, there are overloads of `SelectMany` that make it really easy to compose observables with `Task<T>`.  (Just be aware of the [additional concurrency](https://rx.codeplex.com/workitem/48) that may be introduced by these and similar Task/Observable coop operators.)

```
var q = from value in src
        from _ in F(value.X).AsVoidAsync()  // See helper definition below
        from __ in F(value.Y).AsVoidAsync()
        select value;
```

However, based on the fact that you specifically asked about the `Do` operator, I suspect that **src** may contain more than one value and you don't want overlapping calls to **F** for each value either.  In that case, consider that `SelectMany` is actually just like `Select->Merge`; therefore, what you probably want is `Select->Concat`.

```
// using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks

var q = src.Select(x => Observable.Defer(() => F(x).ToObservable())).Concat();
```

Don't forget to use `Defer` since `F(x)` is *hot*.

**AsVoidAsync Extension**:

`IObservable<T>` requires a **T**, yet `Task` represents *void*, thus Rx's conversion operators require us to get a `Task<T>` from a `Task`.  I tend to use Rx's [System.Reactive.Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit.aspx) struct for `T`:

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
  public static Task<Unit> AsVoidAsync(this Task task)
  {
    return task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Unit>();

      if (t.IsCanceled)
      {
        tcs.SetCanceled();
      }
      else if (t.IsFaulted)
      {
        tcs.SetException(t.Exception);
      }
      else
      {
        tcs.SetResult(Unit.Default);
      }

      return tcs.Task;
    },
    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously)
    .Unwrap();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could always just call the specialized [ToObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211785(v=vs.103).aspx) method instead.

Comment: There is also a Merge overload with max_concurrent parameter. By setting this parameter to 1, you can achieve similar effect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211914(v=vs.103).aspx

See the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436542/converting-a-ienumerablet-to-iobservablet-with-maximum-parallelism

Comment: That's not an approach I'd recommend though.  1. It's not immediately obvious that Merge(1) behaves like Concat.  Concat has the correct semantics.  2. The implementation of Concat calls Merge(1) already (proving my first point).  3. The cost of Merge(1) could theoretically be slightly greater than Concat, since the former was designed to achieve bounded concurrency.  The lower bound isn't necessarily implemented as a hot path.  (I know it's a moot point due to #2, but that's an internal implementation detail that could change.)